# Generic GDI+ Error When screenshot is taken C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF toolbar app with some small commands. One of them is a screenshot button. When I press the button I get a

"System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'" error. Anyone know how to fix this?

My code: (error is thrown @                 bitmap.Save("C:\Screenshots\" + filename);

```
      Rectangle rect = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
            
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    
                    g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, rect.Size);
                }
                String filename = "ToolbarSnap" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-hhmmss") + ".png";
                bitmap.Save("C:\\Screenshots\\" + filename);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure that the destination directory exists, and that you have write permissions in it, your code should work.

To make sure, you can add:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
```

Before your screenshot code.